# How to find and change inner text of xml elements? C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xelement

I have a following xml file. I need to change the inner text of **ANY tag**, which contains the value «**Museum**», or just a tag for a start:

```
<src>
   <riga>
      <com>&#190;</com>
      <riquadro797>Direction to move</riquadro797>
   </riga>
   <riga>
      <llt>
         <com>Museum</com>
         <elemento797>Direction not to move</elemento797>
      </llt>
   </riga>
  <operation>
      <com>&#160;</com>
      <riquadro797>Museum</riquadro797>
  </operation> 
  <riga>
    <gt>
        <elemento797>Direction not to move</elemento797>
    </gt>
 </riga>    
</src>
```

I've parsed this file to XElement. What I've tried and it dos not work:

```
var tt = xmlCluster.Elements(First(x => x.Value == "Museum");
```

This code is not proper, as I cannot predict which element will contain "Museum":

```
 var el = rootElRecDocXml.SelectSingleNode("src/riga/gt/elemento797[text()='"+mFilePath+"']");
```

How to do it? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you even tried doing a google search on `Parsing XElement C#`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just grab all elements with `Museum` values:

```
 var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
 var elements = doc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Value == "Museum");

 foreach (var ele in elements)
    ele.Value = "Test";

 //doc is updated with new values
```

as Selman22 noted, doc will just be a working copy of your xml.  You'll need to call `doc.Save` to apply anything back to the disk, or wherever you need

Comment: you should note that this changes won't affect actual document unless you save it.

Comment: @Selman22 why on Earth would you have to tell a person that. `Please note that anything will not be saved unless you save it`.... Duh?

Comment: because it is true. someone who didn't use Linq to XML before could easily think this will affect the document itself. apperantely you haven't seen enough question here otherwise you would get my point.

Answer (score 1):

Elements() only looks at a single level in the heirarchy. I think you want Descendants() instead...

Answer (score 1):

If you want an older-school XPath option, you need to do a global search on the tree - you can use the [`//`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) XPath expression for this:

```
var els = rootElRecDocXml.SelectNodes("//[text()='"+mFilePath+"']");
```